# Is there a way to speed up my MySQL execution time?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Update: I have removed the duplicate connections, which reduced the time down to 18 seconds. Other improvements would be appreciated as well!

I feel like I have some massive oversight that is causing it to take exponentially longer than it should for the very few items I have in the database. Right now, there are only about 85 entities in my database, but running my Java program takes 51 seconds. For 40 entities, it took 35 seconds, so clearly I'm doing something wrong. This database will eventually have millions of entities in it, which would take days to complete a single run. Can anyone tell me what optimizations I should do? Please note I am a total beginner when it comes to MySQL and especially Java MySQL implementation, so please go easy on me.

Here is the problem code:

```java
public static void SQL() {
    int handleqty = -1;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://MYURL:3306/MYDB";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    try{
        Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        for(Entry<String, String> entry: passToSQL.entrySet()) {
            
            //System.out.println(entry);

            String cardinfo = entry.getValue();
            
            String Handle = cardinfo.split(",")[0];
            String Title = cardinfo.split(",")[1];
            String Vendor = cardinfo.split(",")[2];
            String Tags = cardinfo.split(",")[3];
            String Published = cardinfo.split(",")[4];
            String Option1Name = cardinfo.split(",")[5];
            String Option1Value = cardinfo.split(",")[6];
            int VariantGrams = Integer.parseInt(cardinfo.split(",")[7]);
            String VariantInventoryTracker = cardinfo.split(",")[8];
            String VariantInventoryQty = cardinfo.split(",")[9];
            String VariantInventoryPolicy = cardinfo.split(",")[10];
            String VariantFufillmentService = cardinfo.split(",")[11];
            float VariantPrice =  Float.parseFloat(cardinfo.split(",")[12]);
            String VariantRequiresShipping = cardinfo.split(",")[13];
            String VariantTaxable = cardinfo.split(",")[14];
            String ImgSrcfront = cardinfo.split(",")[15];
            String ImgSrcback = cardinfo.split(",")[16];
            String GiftCard = cardinfo.split(",")[17];
            String Status = cardinfo.split(",")[18];
            String Description = cardinfo.split(",")[19];
            
            String checkexists = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MasterCardRecord WHERE Handle = ? LIMIT 1)";
            PreparedStatement statement1 = conn1.prepareStatement(checkexists);
            statement1.setString(1, Handle);
            ResultSet exists = statement1.executeQuery();
            exists.next();
            //System.out.println(exists.getString(1));
            boolean handleexists = false;
            if(exists.getString(1).equals("1")) {
                handleexists = true;
                

//REMOVED: Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,    password);

                String sql2 = "SELECT `Variant Inventory Qty` FROM MasterCardRecord WHERE Handle = ? LIMIT 1";
                PreparedStatement getqty = conn1.prepareStatement(sql2);
                getqty.setString(1, Handle);
                ResultSet handleqtyrs = getqty.executeQuery();
                handleqtyrs.next();
                handleqty = handleqtyrs.getInt(1);
                
            }
            if(exists.getString(1).equals("0")) {
                handleexists = false;
            }
            
            statement1.close();
           // REMOVED: conn1.close();
            
            //NEW CODE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (handleexists == true) {
                //REMOVED: Connection connInvUpdate= DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                String InvUpdate = "INSERT INTO InventoryUpdate (Handle, `Variant Inventory Qty`) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Variant Inventory Qty` = ?";
                PreparedStatement InvStatement = conn1.prepareStatement(InvUpdate);
                InvStatement.setString(1,Handle);
                InvStatement.setInt(2, handleqty + 1);
                InvStatement.setInt(3, handleqty + 1);
                int updatedInv = InvStatement.executeUpdate();
                //REMOVED: connInvUpdate.close();
                InvStatement.close();
            
            
            
            
            
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
            if(handleexists == false) {
                // Handle doesnt exist within database
                 //REMOVED: Connection conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                 String sql = "INSERT INTO MasterCardRecord (Handle, Title, Vendor, Tags, Published, Option1Name, Option1Value, VariantGrams, `Variant Inventory Tracker`, `Variant Inventory Qty`, `Variant Inventory Policy`, `Variant Fufillment Service`, `Variant Price`, `Variant Requires Shipping`, `Variant Taxable`, `Img Src(front)`, `Img Src(back)`, `Gift Card`, Status, Description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                 PreparedStatement statement2 = conn1.prepareStatement(sql);
                 statement2.setString(1, Handle);
                 statement2.setString(2, Title);
                 statement2.setString(3, Vendor);
                 statement2.setString(4, Tags);
                 statement2.setString(5, Published);
                 statement2.setString(6, Option1Name);
                 statement2.setString(7, Option1Value);
                 statement2.setInt(8, VariantGrams);
                 statement2.setString(9, VariantInventoryTracker);
                 statement2.setString(10, VariantInventoryQty);
                 statement2.setString(11, VariantInventoryPolicy);
                 statement2.setString(12, VariantFufillmentService);
                 statement2.setFloat(13, VariantPrice);
                 statement2.setString(14, VariantRequiresShipping);
                 statement2.setString(15, VariantTaxable);
                 statement2.setString(16, ImgSrcfront);
                 statement2.setString(17, ImgSrcback);
                 statement2.setString(18, GiftCard);
                 statement2.setString(19, Status);
                 statement2.setString(20, Description);
                  
                 int rows = statement2.executeUpdate();
                 if (rows > 0 && showupdates == true) {
                     System.out.println("Item Added: " + Handle);
                 }
                 statement2.close();
                 //REMOVED: conn3.close();
                 
                 // Put into AddNewCards as well, for export and adding ONLY those cards that dont exist yet.
                 Connection AddNewCardConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                 String AddNewCardSQL = "INSERT INTO AddNewCards (Handle, Title, Vendor, Tags, Published, Option1Name, Option1Value, VariantGrams, `Variant Inventory Tracker`, `Variant Inventory Qty`, `Variant Inventory Policy`, `Variant Fufillment Service`, `Variant Price`, `Variant Requires Shipping`, `Variant Taxable`, `Img Src(front)`, `Img Src(back)`, `Gift Card`, Status, Description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                 PreparedStatement AddNewCardStatement = conn1.prepareStatement(AddNewCardSQL);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(1, Handle);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(2, Title);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(3, Vendor);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(4, Tags);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(5, Published);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(6, Option1Name);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(7, Option1Value);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setInt(8, VariantGrams);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(9, VariantInventoryTracker);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(10, VariantInventoryQty);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(11, VariantInventoryPolicy);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(12, VariantFufillmentService);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setFloat(13, VariantPrice);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(14, VariantRequiresShipping);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(15, VariantTaxable);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(16, ImgSrcfront);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(17, ImgSrcback);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(18, GiftCard);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(19, Status);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(20, Description);
                 
                 
                 int AddCardRows = AddNewCardStatement.executeUpdate();
                 AddNewCardStatement.close();
                 //REMOVED: AddNewCardConn.close();
                 
                 
                 
            }
            if (handleexists == true) {
                // Handle DOES exist within database
                 //REMOVED: Connection conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                 String sql = "UPDATE MasterCardRecord SET `Variant Inventory Qty` = ? WHERE Handle = ?";
                 PreparedStatement statement2 = conn3.prepareStatement(sql);
                 statement2.setInt(1,handleqty + 1);
                 statement2.setString(2, Handle);
                 int rows = statement2.executeUpdate();
                 if (rows > 0 && showupdates == true) {
                     System.out.println("Inventory of: " + Handle + "has been updated from " + handleqty + " to %d".formatted(handleqty + 1));
                 }
                 statement2.close();
                 //REMOVED: conn3.close();
            }            
       
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Database connection failed!\n" + e);
        }

    }
//ADDED: 
conn1.close();

}
```

The purpose of this code is to take in some data in a map that was gathered from a CSV file, then go through that map and input the data into 3 different tables.

1. MasterCardRecord : This table holds every card and its overall qty and other values
2. AddNewCards : This table contains the information for new cards only, to allow for import into another website of ONLY cards new to the database
3. Inventory Update: This table contains the handle and qty of cards that are already in the database, to allow for quick quantity updates of those cards

I tried to be clear with the problem, but if more information is needed, here is a pastebin of the full code: https://pastebin.com/TQ54f6gB
Images of database structure:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcwMa.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgpJB.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpYdh.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkwFK.png

As requested, here is the text format of the photos:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `AddNewCards` (
  `Handle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Vendor` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'the10thinningva.com',
  `Tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Published` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'FALSE',
  `Option1Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Title',
  `Option1Value` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Default Title',
  `VariantGrams` decimal(4,0) DEFAULT '45',
  `Variant Inventory Tracker` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'shopify',
  `Variant Inventory Qty` int DEFAULT '1',
  `Variant Inventory Policy` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'deny',
  `Variant Fufillment Service` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'manual',
  `Variant Price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `Variant Requires Shipping` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'TRUE',
  `Variant Taxable` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'TRUE',
  `Img Src(front)` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Img Src(back)` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gift Card` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'FALSE',
  `Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'active',
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Handle`),
  UNIQUE KEY `handle_UNIQUE` (`Handle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `InventoryUpdate` (
  `Handle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Variant Inventory Qty` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Handle`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Handle_UNIQUE` (`Handle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `MasterCardRecord` (
  `Handle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Vendor` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'the10thinningva.com',
  `Tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Published` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'FALSE',
  `Option1Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Title',
  `Option1Value` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Default Title',
  `VariantGrams` decimal(4,0) DEFAULT '45',
  `Variant Inventory Tracker` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'shopify',
  `Variant Inventory Qty` int DEFAULT '1',
  `Variant Inventory Policy` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'deny',
  `Variant Fufillment Service` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'manual',
  `Variant Price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `Variant Requires Shipping` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'TRUE',
  `Variant Taxable` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'TRUE',
  `Img Src(front)` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Img Src(back)` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gift Card` varchar(5) DEFAULT 'FALSE',
  `Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'active',
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Handle`),
  UNIQUE KEY `handle_UNIQUE` (`Handle`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

An example of an entry is as follows:

```
'1989-fleer-#nno-california-angels-team-stickers-(one-logo)', '1989 Fleer #NNO California Angels Team Stickers (One Logo)', 'websitelink.com', 'collectable', 'TRUE', 'Title', 'Default Title', '45', 'shopify', '12', 'deny', 'manual', '2.00', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'https://linktoajpg_front.jpg', 'https://linktoajpg_back.jpg', 'FALSE', 'active', '1989 Fleer #NNO California Angels Team Stickers (One Logo)'
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Adding the DDL of your tables to the question would be helpful. For instance, do you have an index on the `handle` column? That may help.

Comment: I have provided the DDL requested in text format. an example of an entry has been added for context as well.

Comment: You can create your prepared statements before your loop, just after you create the connection. Then where you close your statements at present, just close the ResultSets instead. Not certain how much that will help.

Comment: Hello. I dont know what i did, i think i accidentally had 2 connections instead of 1 like i thought and fixed that, but i got the time down to 6 seconds. Moving prepared statements and closing resultsets did not noticeably impact time, but may have helped in the future when the time is higher(i only measure seconds currently). Is 6 seconds normal for a SQL query time, or is that still long for such a small database? I feel like it should be doing it almost instantly, but i do not know if thats a based assumption or not.

Comment: `passToSQL` has 85 items in it?

Comment: Another small improvement is to remove the SELECT EXISTS... query and just do the SELECT VariantInventoryQuantity... query. If `handleqtyrs.next()` is false, that means that the handle didn't exist, so you kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: yes it has about 80 items in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one single connection, opening a lot of connection is resource consuming see this post [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532225/is-it-better-to-have-one-always-open-connection-or-is-it-better-to-establish-a-c), at least close the opened connections.

Also try to separate your code into functions, example update, retrieve, add must have their own functions.

EDIT:

```
    public static void SQL() {
    int handleqty = -1;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://MYURL:3306/MYDB";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    try{
        Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        String cardinfo = "";
        String Handle = "";
        String Title = "";
        String Vendor = "";
        String Tags = "";
        String Published = "";
        String Option1Name = "";
        String Option1Value = "";
        int VariantGrams = "";
        String VariantInventoryTracker = "";
        String VariantInventoryQty = "";
        String VariantInventoryPolicy = "";
        String VariantFufillmentService = "";
        float VariantPrice =  "";
        String VariantRequiresShipping = "";
        String VariantTaxable = "";
        String ImgSrcfront = "";
        String ImgSrcback = "";
        String GiftCard = "";
        String Status = "";
        String Description = "";
        for(Entry<String, String> entry: passToSQL.entrySet()) {
            
            //System.out.println(entry);

            cardinfo = entry.getValue();
            
            Handle = cardinfo.split(",")[0];
            Title = cardinfo.split(",")[1];
            Vendor = cardinfo.split(",")[2];
            Tags = cardinfo.split(",")[3];
            Published = cardinfo.split(",")[4];
            Option1Name = cardinfo.split(",")[5];
            Option1Value = cardinfo.split(",")[6];
            VariantGrams = Integer.parseInt(cardinfo.split(",")[7]);
            VariantInventoryTracker = cardinfo.split(",")[8];
            VariantInventoryQty = cardinfo.split(",")[9];
            VariantInventoryPolicy = cardinfo.split(",")[10];
            VariantFufillmentService = cardinfo.split(",")[11];
            VariantPrice =  Float.parseFloat(cardinfo.split(",")[12]);
            VariantRequiresShipping = cardinfo.split(",")[13];
            VariantTaxable = cardinfo.split(",")[14];
            ImgSrcfront = cardinfo.split(",")[15];
            ImgSrcback = cardinfo.split(",")[16];
            GiftCard = cardinfo.split(",")[17];
            Status = cardinfo.split(",")[18];
            Description = cardinfo.split(",")[19];
            
            String checkexists = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MasterCardRecord WHERE Handle = ? LIMIT 1)";
            PreparedStatement statement1 = conn1.prepareStatement(checkexists);
            statement1.setString(1, Handle);
            ResultSet exists = statement1.executeQuery();
            exists.next();
            //System.out.println(exists.getString(1));
            boolean handleexists = false;
            if(exists.getString(1).equals("1")) {
                handleexists = true;
                

//REMOVED: Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,    password);

                String sql2 = "SELECT `Variant Inventory Qty` FROM MasterCardRecord WHERE Handle = ? LIMIT 1";
                PreparedStatement getqty = conn1.prepareStatement(sql2);
                getqty.setString(1, Handle);
                ResultSet handleqtyrs = getqty.executeQuery();
                handleqtyrs.next();
                handleqty = handleqtyrs.getInt(1);
                
            }
            if(exists.getString(1).equals("0")) {
                handleexists = false;
            }
            
            statement1.close();
           // REMOVED: conn1.close();
            
            //NEW CODE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (handleexists == true) {
                //REMOVED: Connection connInvUpdate= DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                String InvUpdate = "INSERT INTO InventoryUpdate (Handle, `Variant Inventory Qty`) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Variant Inventory Qty` = ?";
                PreparedStatement InvStatement = conn1.prepareStatement(InvUpdate);
                InvStatement.setString(1,Handle);
                InvStatement.setInt(2, handleqty + 1);
                InvStatement.setInt(3, handleqty + 1);
                int updatedInv = InvStatement.executeUpdate();
                //REMOVED: connInvUpdate.close();
                InvStatement.close();
            
            
            
            
            
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
            if(handleexists == false) {
                // Handle doesnt exist within database
                 //REMOVED: Connection conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                 String sql = "INSERT INTO MasterCardRecord (Handle, Title, Vendor, Tags, Published, Option1Name, Option1Value, VariantGrams, `Variant Inventory Tracker`, `Variant Inventory Qty`, `Variant Inventory Policy`, `Variant Fufillment Service`, `Variant Price`, `Variant Requires Shipping`, `Variant Taxable`, `Img Src(front)`, `Img Src(back)`, `Gift Card`, Status, Description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                 PreparedStatement statement2 = conn1.prepareStatement(sql);
                 statement2.setString(1, Handle);
                 statement2.setString(2, Title);
                 statement2.setString(3, Vendor);
                 statement2.setString(4, Tags);
                 statement2.setString(5, Published);
                 statement2.setString(6, Option1Name);
                 statement2.setString(7, Option1Value);
                 statement2.setInt(8, VariantGrams);
                 statement2.setString(9, VariantInventoryTracker);
                 statement2.setString(10, VariantInventoryQty);
                 statement2.setString(11, VariantInventoryPolicy);
                 statement2.setString(12, VariantFufillmentService);
                 statement2.setFloat(13, VariantPrice);
                 statement2.setString(14, VariantRequiresShipping);
                 statement2.setString(15, VariantTaxable);
                 statement2.setString(16, ImgSrcfront);
                 statement2.setString(17, ImgSrcback);
                 statement2.setString(18, GiftCard);
                 statement2.setString(19, Status);
                 statement2.setString(20, Description);
                  
                 int rows = statement2.executeUpdate();
                 if (rows > 0 && showupdates == true) {
                     System.out.println("Item Added: " + Handle);
                 }
                 statement2.close();
                 //REMOVED: conn3.close();
                 
                 // Put into AddNewCards as well, for export and adding ONLY those cards that dont exist yet.
                 //-----> remove thisConnection AddNewCardConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                 String AddNewCardSQL = "INSERT INTO AddNewCards (Handle, Title, Vendor, Tags, Published, Option1Name, Option1Value, VariantGrams, `Variant Inventory Tracker`, `Variant Inventory Qty`, `Variant Inventory Policy`, `Variant Fufillment Service`, `Variant Price`, `Variant Requires Shipping`, `Variant Taxable`, `Img Src(front)`, `Img Src(back)`, `Gift Card`, Status, Description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                 PreparedStatement AddNewCardStatement = conn1.prepareStatement(AddNewCardSQL);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(1, Handle);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(2, Title);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(3, Vendor);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(4, Tags);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(5, Published);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(6, Option1Name);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(7, Option1Value);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setInt(8, VariantGrams);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(9, VariantInventoryTracker);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(10, VariantInventoryQty);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(11, VariantInventoryPolicy);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(12, VariantFufillmentService);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setFloat(13, VariantPrice);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(14, VariantRequiresShipping);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(15, VariantTaxable);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(16, ImgSrcfront);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(17, ImgSrcback);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(18, GiftCard);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(19, Status);
                 AddNewCardStatement.setString(20, Description);
                 
                 
                 int AddCardRows = AddNewCardStatement.executeUpdate();
                 AddNewCardStatement.close();
                 //REMOVED: AddNewCardConn.close();
                 
                 
                 
            }
            if (handleexists == true) {
                // Handle DOES exist within database
                 //REMOVED: Connection conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                 String sql = "UPDATE MasterCardRecord SET `Variant Inventory Qty` = ? WHERE Handle = ?";
                 PreparedStatement statement2 = conn3.prepareStatement(sql);
                 statement2.setInt(1,handleqty + 1);
                 statement2.setString(2, Handle);
                 int rows = statement2.executeUpdate();
                 if (rows > 0 && showupdates == true) {
                     System.out.println("Inventory of: " + Handle + "has been updated from " + handleqty + " to %d".formatted(handleqty + 1));
                 }
                 statement2.close();
                 //REMOVED: conn3.close();
            }            
       
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Database connection failed!\n" + e);
        }

    }
//ADDED: 
conn1.close();

}
```

Comment: Hello, That has reduced the time down to 18 seconds, so only ~30% of the original time! For some reason i thought i needed a new connection for each command but clearly not haha! this was a really good improvement, thank you! if you can think of anything else please let me know

Comment: you can use a hashmap, instead of splitting each string use regular expression to split the whole string into an array.

Comment: Is a hashmap not basically the same as the map(which i used)?if it is, can you explain the differences(online it says theyre basically the same) and if it is not different, can you explain how id implement it properly VS the way i did it improperly? This was my first time using a map so im sure i did it horribly, so any pointers would be appreciated! @Tayeb HAMDAOUI

Comment: no they are not the same, map is an interface and hashmap is a class, see this: https://www.ksolves.com/blog/java/difference-between-map-and-hashmap-in-java#:~:text=HashMap%20is%20a%20non%2Dsynchronized,to%20map%20key%2Dpair%20values.  another thing you can improve is declaring variables outside the for loop, if you have 80 rows, and each row has 20 element then you are creating 400 distinct variables, and your code is too long, seperate each into a function.

Answer (score 0):

`PRIMARY KEY(HANDLE)` provides a Unique Index on `HANDLE`, so drop

```
UNIQUE KEY `handle_UNIQUE` (`Handle`)
```

Looking at

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MasterCardRecord WHERE Handle = ? LIMIT 1)
```

Get rid of `LIMIT 1`.  `EXISTS` stops when it gets success.

Looking at

```
SELECT `Variant Inventory Qty` FROM MasterCardRecord WHERE Handle = ? LIMIT 1
```

This could serve as an existence check.  That is, see if you can get rid of the previous query.

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` leads to getting some random result.  If you can't have multiple rows, then the `LIMIT` is misleading; if you care which of many rows you get, then consider adding an `ORDER BY`.

SQL is much better at doing many rows at once than going back and forth from the app.  Can your `SELECT` fetch all the relevant rows?  Better yet, can the IODKU act on all the necessary rows at once?

If you want more help, try to boil down the code to one screen full.  I don't need to see all the app code building and checking values -- *unless* the sluggishness is really in that code!